# Why isn't there a legitimate way to vertically align elements?

Tags: html, css, layout, vertical-alignment

CSS is a wonderful thing, but why isn't there an official "standard" way vertically align divs and text inside of other containers? I **refuse** to use tables in my layout, cause let's face it, it's not the 90's anymore!

I know there are ways to make content appear vertically centered, using margins/padding or vertical-align with a line-height in place (which isn't optimal at all). Using margins doesn't work if you have a div that has a specified height in the same container as text content that you want to be vertically centered, as text size varies between browsers, so it won't actually be centered in all browsers.

Does **ANYBODY** know if there is, or when there will be, a way to easily center content vertically with CSS only, and not using tables in current, modern, browsers?

Answer (score 2):

Well i suggest using some lightweight jQuery plugin, that is flexible for all your needs. Here's example:

```
(function ($) {
// VERTICALLY ALIGN FUNCTION
$.fn.vAlign = function() {
    return this.each(function(i){
    var ah = $(this).height();
    var ph = $(this).parent().height();
    var mh = Math.ceil((ph-ah) / 2);
    $(this).css('margin-top', mh);
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

Then u just use the function on the selector that you want:

```
$('#example p').vAlign();
```

Comment: Maybe... if I used jQuery, also how would this apply to text alignment?

Comment: you can margin-top any element, despite if it's text or not, in my example its paragraph

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle"> ... </div>
```

I think you listed all the other methods

Comment: is that supported by all browsers?

Comment: Is anything CSS supported by ALL browsers? I'd check a website like http://caniuse.com/ or similar to decide if you want to use various CSS options.